# Python filter from array list based on multiple condition

Tags: python

I wanted to filter an array. The array as follows
Input:

```
list = [{
        "email": "test@mail.com",
        "name": "first name"
    },
    {
        "email": "test1@gmail.com",
        "name": "second name"
    }]
```

I want to filter this array like with keyword email="test1@gmail.com" and name="second name" by and condition so if email and name is satisfy from the array then will return this like below
output:

```
{
  "email": "test1@gmail.com",
  "name": "second name"
}
```

so If I pass the filter to a def then this will return filter

```
def filterData(list, email, name):
    //return filtered data based on params
```

This issue have solved by bellow code

```
contacts = [{
    "email": "test@mail.com",
    "name": "first name"
},
{
    "email": "test1@gmail.com",
    "name": "second name"
}]

email = 'test1@gmail.com'
name = 'second name'

filters = [
    lambda contact: contact['email'] == email, # filter by email
    lambda contact: contact['name'] == name, # filter by name
] # custom filters

print(
    list(filter(
        lambda contact: all(func(contact) for func in filters),
        contacts
    ))
)
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot to show the code you're having trouble with

Comment: What you call "array" is not an [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) but a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-list). You even call this variable `list` - which is a bad decision because you overwrite the built-in function [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some builtin functions and custom filters like:

```py
contacts = [{
    "email": "test@mail.com",
    "name": "first name"
},
{
    "email": "test1@gmail.com",
    "name": "second name"
}]

email = 'test1@gmail.com'
name = 'second name'

filters = [
    lambda contact: contact['email'] == email, # filter by email
    lambda contact: contact['name'] == name, # filter by name
] # custom filters

print(
    list(filter(
        lambda contact: all(func(contact) for func in filters),
        contacts
    ))
)
```

Each lambda function in the `filters` list is called with the current contact as a parameter, this creates a new list with Boolean, and the `all` function returns `True` just in case all values are equal to `True`.

If you prefer, you can replace the `all` function with the `any` function, it returns `True` if any value in the list is `True`

Comment: can I make in function so this should filter like if email:  then will filter by email and if name: then will filter by name and if email and name: then will filter by both?

Comment: Yes. With the `all` function you will only have the data that passes through all the filters in the `filters` list (like an `and` operator), but if you want it to return even if you pass it through just one (like an `or` operator) , just change the `all` function to `any`

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve by using list comprehension and using condition

```py
[x for x in list if <condition>]

# in your case, it will be:
output = [x for x in list if (x["email"] == "test1@gmail.com" and x["name"] == "second name")])
print(output)
```

Answer (score 2):

Define the condition (using def or lambda) along with using built-in list filter

```py
def my_condition(item):
    return item["email"] == "test1@gmail.com" and item["name"] == "second name"
    
result = list(filter(my_condition, my_list))
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
lst = [
    {
        "email": "test@mail.com",
        "name": "first name"
    },
    {
        "email": "test1@gmail.com",
        "name": "second name"
    }
]

filtered_lst = [item for item in lst if item["email"] == "test1@gmail.com" and item["name"] == "second name"]

# If there are multiple matching items, filtered_lst will contain all of them.
# In this case, since there's only one matching item, we'll access it using [0].
output = filtered_lst[0]

print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

A more optimized way would be to use Python's built-in `next` function in combination with a generator expression, which avoids the need to iterate over the entire list once a match is found:

```
input_list = [
    {
        "email": "test@mail.com",
        "name": "first name"
    },
    {
        "email": "test1@gmail.com",
        "name": "second name"
    }
]

def filter_list(lst, email, name):
    return next((item for item in lst if item['email'] == email and item['name'] == name), None)

filtered_item = filter_list(input_list, "test1@gmail.com", "second name")

print(filtered_item)
```

It will stop iterating over the list as soon as it finds a matching item and return it. This might be a more optimized option especially when if your list is huge.